# launchd keep application alive hidden

Tags: macos, launcher, launchd

I try to keep running a program. Everytime it has to be restarted this should be done in the background. I use the following code, but the program window pops up after my MacBook awakes from sleep and I log in. Any ideas how to avoid this?

Thank You!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>user.launchkeep.bettertouchtool</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>open</string>
    <string>-gjWa</string>
    <string>BetterTouchTool</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this with root privileges or in user scope?

Answer (score 0):

From the plist, it looks like you are running a LaunchAgent. Since LaunchAgent runs in user scope, it runs only if the user is logged in.

If you need a process to be running throughout, irrespective of user logins, you can create a LaunchDaemon.

Comment: Using it as LaunchDaemon does not change anything. Still it is kept alive. But everytime my Mac awakes from sleep and I log in, the window of the program pops up. It is not kept hide anymore then.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on your use case? Are you having an app with a window? When do you want the window to pop up?

Comment: Of course I can. I use a program which observes keyboard actions, so that specific shortcuts are executed by the program. It has a window changes can be done in. I do not want the window to pop up at any time. The program should run in the background always. Everytime my MacBook turns into sleep mode and is awaked, the app is shut down. So I want to use a launchagent to keep it alive not to have to start it manually. But the job above makes the window pop up after logging in when awaking the Mac from sleep. I can't explain why this happens, because the parameters -gjWa are used.

Comment: What kind of changes expected to be done in the window? Is it some settings changes, key-mapping etc? If this is the case, why dont you go with a menu bar extras?

Comment: KeepAlive flag in a LaunchAgent will just ensure that it starts on login and restarts in case it stops/crashes.

Comment: Menu bar extras does not allow me to open specific folders or place windows using keyboard shortcuts. These features are added by the program. The windows is not wanted to be shown any time. "KeepAlive flag in a LaunchAgent will just ensure that it starts on login and restarts in case it stops/crashes." That's exactly what I want, but as I said I never want the window to be shown in case it is restarted.

Comment: Then you have to look into your code and see where it is opening a window. From what you have said, it might be happening at startup. Disable that code and let the window come up only on a key press ... I think this is more of a coding issue

Answer (score 0):

-g just means "Do not bring the application to the foreground". It is not the same as "Start the app hidden". So the app is started visible but furthest back in the app-switcher.

What you want is a script that first starts the app and then hides it. Can be done with Applescript.